# How to display code modules(.cs) as items in a listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, module, listbox

I'm currently working on a new GUI that has a **listbox** as a crucial element in it. So far I've managed to display and select **multiple items** in this listbox, which wasn't that big of a deal.

My goal is to have several **.cs files**(maybe in further expansion als vb script files) in a **folder within the project**, which are properly displayed in the main view listbox and will be executed if the corresponding item in the listbox is selected.

So far I've tried to build the listbox and all the other GUI stuff (buttons, text,...) and connected the listbox with a bindable collection of a script model(which is a own class for testing purposes at the moment and should be replaced with the correct .cs files)

In the code below you can see the work around with this custom class and the selection check for multiple listbox items.

```
private void Run_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Show user the scripts which are being processed, these are the previous selected Scripts
            List<string> selectedList = new List<string>();
            foreach (ScriptModel selectedScript in MainListBox.SelectedItems)
            {
                selectedList.Add(selectedScript.Name.ToString());
            }
            //check if no Script was selected, and if so, just return/do nothing
            if (selectedList.Count() == 0) { return; }
            MessageBox.Show("The following Scripts will be processed: " + Environment.NewLine +
                    string.Join(Environment.NewLine, selectedList));


           //Call the Connection for Data-Export 

        }
```

```
private BindableCollection<ScriptModel> _scriptscollection=new BindableCollection<ScriptModel>();

public BindableCollection<ScriptModel> ScriptsCollection
        {
            get { return _scriptscollection; }
            set { _scriptscollection = value; }
        }
```

*I would like to know, how I can replace(or connect) these custom class with actual .cs files (which are some kind of scripts) in a project folder, so that I can display these file names and select the corresponding files for execution. (so the connection should work both ways)*

I'm sorry if this question seems a bit weird and general, but I'm really confused about that.

Comment: Not sure I follow. You want to be able to compile and execute user-defined scripts? Please explain the actual problem in your question as I think the listbox is irrelevant.

Comment: You realise chsarp is compiled rather than interpreted? What you're showing is inherently not an interpreted script you can just run.  Showing code in a textbox is by far the simplest part of this.

Comment: These "scripts" are coded by the developer, but for expansions and to be as modular as possible they should stay in their own file, with certain informations passed. If you select 2 "scripts" and click the run button, there should be one connection for external data and the scripts which are selected should export certain parts of the dataset to an excel file.

Comment: **This is a very very bad approach to making your application expandable.** Research design patterns and see which ones fit your use case. Do not read and compile "scripts" from disk.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I am shifting designs for this case :) (currently reading MVVM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have over complicated the matter. Here is the code that will find all of the .cs files in a directory and then upon selecting one in the `ListBox` will start that file.

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking for but hopefully this helps.

XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ScriptFiles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedScript}"/>
```

Code behind / ViewModel

```
public List<string> ScriptFiles => Directory.GetFiles(FilePath, "*.cs").ToList();

private string selectedScript;
public string SelectedScript
{
    get { return selectedScript; }
    set { selectedScript = value; Process.Start(value); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try that after my class.

Comment: if you just want to: display all cs files in a location, run that cs file when you click on it in the `ListBox` then this will be fine.

Comment: Thanks again. It's working fine so far, I just have to adjust some things for specific usage.

Comment: Good to hear, let me know if you need anything else. I would also suggest taking a good look at MVVM if you're not to familiar and get an understanding of how that works etc. :)